# How do margins work with div positioning?

Tags: css, html, positioning

The `#content` div holds most of the web content. As you can see below, there is a top margin of 280px, because that is the height of the header image of the site, which is placed in the 'body' as a background (image/sky1.jpg).

How do I position a div as a holder above the 'margin' of the `#content` div so that I could place my `#navigation`, `#Title` divs above the header image?

The `#top-float` div just above the #content div was the start of it but each time I add more to the height the
'margin' get affected pushing it below.

I tried putting the `<div id="top-float></div>` above the `<div id="content"></div>` in the html. Is this how should I position this?

```
html {
    background: #73ADD7 url(images/gradient.gif) repeat-x;
}
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background:url(images/sky1.jpg) no-repeat center top;
    color: #666;
    width: 100%;
    display: table; 
}
#top-float{
    padding-left:2.3em;
    padding-right:2.3em;
    height:10em;
}
#content {
    width: 890px;
    margin: 280px auto 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 0px #ccc;
    padding: 0px;
}
#footer {
    width: 890px;
    margin: px auto 0;
    background:url(images/footer-bg.jpg)
    no-repeat center bottom #fff;
    border: solid 0px #ccc;
    height:250px;
}
```

Comment: Try fixing the language (punctuation). It's quite exhausting to read like this.

Comment: @weiqure - don't worry, at least 4 other people will overwrite each others' edits :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to give your `#top-float` a height of `280px` and drop the `top-margin` for `#content` as such:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html {
        background: #73ADD7 url(images/gradient.gif) repeat-x;
      }
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background:url(images/sky1.jpg) no-repeat center top;
        color: #666;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;     
      }
      #top-float{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0 2.3em;
        height:280px;
      }
      #content {
        width: 890px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: #fff;
        border: solid 0px #ccc;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #footer {
        width: 890px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background:url(images/footer-bg.jpg)
        no-repeat center bottom #fff;
        border: solid 0px #ccc;
        height:250px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="#top-float">
    </div>
    <div id="#content">
    </div>
    <div id="#footer">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you need `em` sizing, then give the children of `#top-float` em sizing, and make sure to give `#top-float` `overflow: hidden;`

If you want your content to appear above your header in your markup for SEO purposes, you can do the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      html {
        background: #73ADD7 url(images/gradient.gif) repeat-x;
      }
      body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background:url(images/sky1.jpg) no-repeat center top;
        color: #666;
        width: 100%;
        display: table;     
      }
      #top-float{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 0 2.3em;
        height:280px;
      }
      #content {
        width: 890px;
        margin: 280px auto 0;
        background: #fff;
        border: solid 0px #ccc;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #footer {
        width: 890px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background:url(images/footer-bg.jpg)
        no-repeat center bottom #fff;
        border: solid 0px #ccc;
        height:250px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="#content">
    </div>
    <div id="#footer">
    </div>
    <div id="#top-float">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for this champion! yeah also thanks to all who replied.  This is awesome site am just a newbie.thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the top margin from your content div, and add the placeholder above it with the height specified.

HTML snip:

```
<body>
  <div id="header">Stuff</div>
  <div id="content">Body stuff.../div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
#content {
  margin-top:0;
}

#header {
  height:280px;
}
```

If it makes more sense for the extra header information to be within the content div (semantically), you can use a negative margin.

HTML snip:

```
<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="header">Stuff</div>
    Body stuff...
  </div>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
#content {
  margin-top:280px;
}

#header {
  margin-top:-280px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a little tricky answering this without also seeing your HTML, but a few suggestions:

- Place your #top-float div outside of your content div
- Use negative margins
- Put your content div flush with the top of the browser with a header div inside. Then put your header image inside your header div as the background image
- it doesn't look like you are centering anything so you can also use absolute positioning for the header div

As always, there is no one way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use absolute or fixed positioning for your #top-float div.

Why do you want to put the header image as a background image?  I think you'll find that it all works out easier if you don't put the site's header image as a background.  It is also common practice that clicking on the site's logo (which I assume is in your header image) takes the user back to the home page.  Making the site's logo a background image effectively disables this feature.